What is the best way to check if ADSL gen2 storage account exists using Python?
My code tries to read a specific file in many storage accounts, and in some occasions the storage account has not yet been created.
What is the most optimal way to check if the storage account exists in Python? I currently use the following code.
from azure.storage.filedatalake import DataLakeServiceClient
from azure.identity import DefaultAzureCredential

credential=DefaultAzureCredential()
service_client=DataLakeServiceClient("https://somerandomaccountname.dfs.core.windows.net",credential=credential)
file_client=service_client.get_file_client(file_system="non_existing",file_path="file.name")
file_client.exists()


After running over a minute, this returns a ServiceRequestError.
ServiceRequestError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x0000021719BE13D0>: Failed to resolve 'somerandomaccountname.blob.core.windows.net' ([Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed)

I can catch this error, but want to reduce the execution time. Any better suggestions?

There is a fairly straightforward capability for checking name availability in the Python management SDK for storage. If the name is not available, then the account exists.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storage-accounts/check-name-availability?view=rest-storagerp-2023-01-01&tabs=Python#storageaccountchecknameavailability
Another approach would be this, probably even faster. Existing storage account names will resolve to some IP, so the below only returns an IP if the account exists.
import socket
accountname = 'name of account you are checking'    
print(socket.gethostbyname(f'{accountname}.blob.core.windows.net'))

